# How to solve Time Out error when downloading cocoapods on macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, cocoapods

i hope everything is going great!

I've been trying to download cocoapods via my macOS Terminal. Whenever i run
`sudo gem install cocoapods` and inputing my password on my terminal i get an error saying:
`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

What can i do to fix this?

Btw, im running on: macOS: 10.15.5, xcode:11.6, terminal: i've tried on bash and default -zsh

Comment: i went on https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods and noticed that ruby version required was >= 2.0.0, so i updated my mac's ruby to 2.7.0 but it still dose not work...still getting the same message...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue...how? I have no idea jajaja

So this is what I did to fix the problem:

1. I was connected to my 2.4 GHz bandwidth internet and decided to change it to my 5.0 GHz bandwidth internet connection.
2. Closed all Terminal windows and quit Terminal.
3. Opened Terminal again and ran `gem uninstall cocoapods`and it returned `Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed`
4. Then I ran `gem install cocoapods`(Note: I did **not** include `sudo`)
5. Waited for the complete download and finally no errors occured and everything finished OK.